# jQuery Validation - submitHandler and AJAX response

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to do a ajax check of username availability and submitting a form only if the username is available.

Using jQuery Validation plugin, I have set:

```
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        if (ajaxCheck() == true){
            alert('true');
        }
    }
```

And my username checking function looks like this:

```
function ajaxCheck(){
usernameVal = $("#username").val().toLowerCase();
usernameVal = usernameVal.replace(/[\s\W]/g, '');
$.post("/app/signup/username/", {
username: usernameVal
}, function(response){
    if (response == "Username not available.") {
        $("#signup").validate().showErrors({ "username" : "Username Not Available." });
        alert('false');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('true');
        return true;
    }
});
```

}

The problem is it's not returning true or false to the submitHandler. I'm not sure if it's because the return statements are within the $.post ?

If I run the ajaxCheck independently, it does alert false and true based on availability, it's just not returning false/true if it's called from submitHandler.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: i think the method gets complets before it returns a value as it is asyncronous call , i am 90% sure about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Novon ,

You can set a variable inside a success of ajax, but to my knowledge you cannot return a value from the ajax.

its a asyncronous call , so maintain a global variable move your logic of checking to the succuess.

You can not make a ajax call and get return value like a method

Answer (score 2):

you can use remote option too, like this!

```
remote: {
    url: myUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/trabajos/json.php?c=wrk&a=validMail',
    type: "post",
    data: {
        correo: function() {
                return $("#subtrabajo_correo").val();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Awesome, working now with:

```
$.validator.addMethod("usercheck", function(value, element) {
        ajaxCheck();
        return validName;
}, "Username not available!");
```

and setting a variable "validName" instead of returning true/false in ajaxCheck();

Comment: how does it even work? validName is not defined anywhere